# The setter 'phone=' was called on null. I/flutter (32048): Receiver: null I/flutter (32048): Tried calling: phone="12357809"

Tags: flutter, dart

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'phone' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: phone= "1235451"

I'm creating a page to update user registration data, and when I click on update this error appears and nothing happens. I'm learning flutter now, and there's a lot that I don't know, can someone help me?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../generated/l10n.dart';
import '../models/user.dart';
import '../helpers/helper.dart';
import '../elements/BlockButtonWidget.dart';
import '../helpers/app_config.dart' as config;

import 'package:mvc_pattern/mvc_pattern.dart';
import '../repository/user_repository.dart' as repository;

import '../repository/user_repository.dart';

class SettingsController extends ControllerMVC {



  GlobalKey<FormState> loginFormKey;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;

  SettingsController() {
    loginFormKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
    this.scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  }

  void update(User user) async {
    user.deviceToken = null;
    repository.update(user).then((value) {
      scaffoldKey?.currentState?.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text("Atualizado com Sucesso"),
      ));
    });
  }
}

class ProfileSettingsDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;
  final VoidCallback onChanged;

  ProfileSettingsDialog({Key key,@required this.user, this.onChanged}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _ProfileSettingsDialogState createState() => _ProfileSettingsDialogState();


}

class _ProfileSettingsDialogState extends State<ProfileSettingsDialog> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _profileSettingsFormKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: Helper.of(context).onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              child: Container(
                width: config.App(context).appWidth(100),
                height: config.App(context).appHeight(29.5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: config.App(context).appHeight(29.5) - 120,
              child: Container(
                width: config.App(context).appWidth(84),
                height: config.App(context).appHeight(29.5),
                child: Text(
                  S.of(context).lets_start_with_register,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2.merge(TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: config.App(context).appHeight(29.5) - 50,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)), boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    blurRadius: 50,
                    color: Theme.of(context).hintColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                  )
                ]),
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 20,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50, horizontal: 27),
                width: config.App(context).appWidth(88),
//              height: config.App(context).appHeight(55),
                child: Form(key: _ProfileSettingsFormKey,


                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        onSaved: (input) => widget.user.phone = input,
                        validator: (input) => input.trim().length < 3 ? S.of(context).not_a_valid_phone : null,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Celular",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                          hintText: S.of(context).john_doe,
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.7)),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_outline, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.2))),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.5))),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.2))),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          onSaved: (input) => widget.user.address = input,
                          validator: (input) => input.trim().length < 3 ? S.of(context).not_a_valid_address : null,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Endereço",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                          hintText: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.7)),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.alternate_email, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.2))),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.5))),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.2))),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          onSaved: (input) => widget.user.bio = input,
                          validator: (input) => input.trim().length < 3 ? S.of(context).not_a_valid_biography : null,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Biografia",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                          hintText: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.7)),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.alternate_email, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.2))),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.5))),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.2))),
                        ),
                      ),

                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      BlockButtonWidget(
                        text: Text(
                          S.of(context).register,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        ),
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,

                        onPressed: () {
                          _profileSettingsFormKey.currentState.save();
                          widget.onChanged();
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          update(currentUser.value);
                              //setState(() {});
                          },
                        //  widget.update(currentUser.value);
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 25),
//                      FlatButton(
//                        onPressed: () {
//                          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/MobileVerification');
//                        },
//                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
//                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.1),
//                        shape: StadiumBorder(),
//                        child: Text(
//                          'Register with Google',
//                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
//                          style: TextStyle(
//                            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
//                          ),
//                        ),
//                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
      
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  InputDecoration getInputDecoration({String hintText, String labelText}) {
    return new InputDecoration(
      hintText: hintText,
      labelText: labelText,
      hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.merge(
            TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor),
          ),
      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor.withOpacity(0.2))),
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor)),
      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
      labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.merge(
            TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor),
          ),
    );
  }



}
```

Comment: How & where did you initialise `ProfileSettingsDialog` ?

Comment: in the Form() .....should i make initstate for the user or add notnull instead of required

Comment: Are you passing valid user object while initialising? It seems like that value is null

Comment: // i got this answer but i dont know how to implement this in code////                     you should try to put user in the state class, as its variables are changing. initialize it in initState function and when you press the button (save button) bounce it up as a param to onPressed

Comment: idhaan ende ippozhathhe avastha

I'm creating a page to update user registration data, and when I click on update this error appears and nothing happens. I'm learning flutter now, and there's a lot that I don't know, can someone help me?

Comment: I don't have insta and not active on any social media except linkedin. If you can make a sample app with the code you've mentioned above and share it with me, I can help you fix the issue.